# SkyDrive broken after upgrade to Windows 8.1: "This location can't be found, please try later"

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, windows-8.1, onedrive

Upgrading from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 via the Store upgrade path has screwed my SkyDrive. The `C:\Users\<user name>\SkyDrive` folder is empty (it only has single file `desktop.ini`). When I open the native (Store) SkyDrive app, I see *"This location can't be found, please try later"*. I'm glad to still have my files alive online in my SkyDrive account.

I tried disconneting from / reconnecting to my Microsoft Account with no luck.

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this without reinstalling/refreshing Windows 8.1?

From Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: skydrive.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16412, time stamp: 0x5243d370
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x00000000
Fault offset: 0x0000000000000000
Faulting process ID: 0x4e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cece256589c7ee
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\skydrive.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: {...}
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Also:

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
 and APPID 
{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

Never was a big fan of in-place upgrade anyway, but this time it was a machine which I use for work, with a lot of stuff already installed on it. Shouldn't have tried to upgrade it in the first place, but was convinced Windows 8.1 is a solid update. Another lesson learnt.

Comment: create a dump file and share the dump: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57

Comment: @magicandre1981, thank you, but I went ahead and reinstalled it from scratch. I wouldn't trust the system with broken integrity like that, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following registry script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{8E74D236-7F35-4720-B138-1FED0B85EA75}]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{8E74D236-7F35-4720-B138-1FED0B85EA75}\ShellFolder]
"Attributes"=dword:00100000
```

Comment: I have already reinstalled Windows, but +1 for trying to help.